# inheritance and polymorphism in LinqToSql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a base class called `BaseEvent`.
And, 3 classes derived from `BaseEvent`: `Derived1, Derived2, Derived3`

Suppose we have a following query:

```
Database.BaseEvents.Where(e => e.EventsCategories.Any(
        c => c.EventCategories== category.OID)).ToList();
```

How to do that this query return collection of derived objects, not BaseEvent?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
[image: picture]

but type should be `Film`

Comment: Could you provide a code example how this array should be hardcoded? For example: List<int> {2,3,5,7} has 4 ints: 2,3,5,7

Comment: As I answered earlier, you need to setup a discriminator field that tells Linq2Sql what derived type to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Cast` method:

```
Database.BaseEvents.Where(e => e.EventsCategories.Any(
    c => c.EventCategories== category.OID)).Cast<DerivedType>().ToList();
```

Assuming that is, you've setup Linq2Sql so that it understands your `EventCategories` property is a [discriminator](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/26/LINQToSQLInheritanceDiscriminatorColumnExampleInheritanceMappingTutorial.aspx).

**Update:**
A discriminator field tells Linq2Sql what type it should use based on the value of a field. If you do not setup such a field. Linq2Sql will always return the base type. A [google query](http://www.google.com/?q=linq2sql+discriminator) will get you a ton of good posts on how to do this.

Comment: but, I dont' know what object will be returned. Suppose this query return 2 objects: derived1 and derived2.

Comment: Cast will throw an exception if there are some BaseEvents which are DerivedType2, but not DerivedType

Comment: @user348173 in that case you cannot do that. If you want to contain list of object with different types, that list should be typed as their common parent type - and that's called polymorphism

Comment: @Archeg Cast will not throw, it will return `null` if the type cannot be cast as requested.

Comment: @MarnixvanValen from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx "If an element cannot be cast to type TResult, this method will throw an exception. To obtain only those elements that can be cast to type TResult, use the OfType<TResult> method instead of Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)."

Answer (score 1):

From the comment I see that you can have different types of derived objects in collection.

In this case don't see any reason to cast the collection to some specific derived type, just return the collection of **base** type, like you do it now. But every **real** object in that collection will have concrete type of `Derived1`, `Derived2`, `Derived3`...

Comment: no, this query return me BaseEvent. See a picture in the question, please

Comment: @user348173: so what the content of that list. ? How do you create and populate that list?

Answer (score -1):

You can use OfType method:

```
Database.BaseEvents.Where(e => e.EventsCategories.Any(
    c => c.EventCategories== category.OID)).OfType<Derived1>.ToList();
```

will return only Derived1 types